# Importing variables from other py files

Tags: django

I have a .py file that contains database settings (call it connection.py). I am trying to import the variables contained in my connection.py into my views.py. However, the variables are not being imported.

In my views.py I have:

```
from connection import *

def location_where_connection_variables_needed(request, some_id):

 conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
 cursor = conn.cursor()
```

I then use the variables in connection.py in my views.py script. But the variables are not being imported into my views.py. I placed connection.py in the main folder (ie, connection.py is in the same folder as my app's folder). Is this the correct place to put this? Or am I doing something else fundamentally wrong?

Edit:
What I mean by not being imported:
I am not getting any error at all but the variables are not being imported because the code in views.py is not executing. If I add the connection variable manually in my views.py, everything works fine.

Connection.py

```
conn_string = "host='localhost' dbname='test' user='postgres' password='pwd'"
```

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what "not working" means?

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Are you getting an ImportError exception? Is the value of some_id empty?

Comment: So sorry for that. I meant to say that the variables from connection.py are not being imported to views.py. I updated the language above.

Comment: Explain "not being imported"...are the values empty? Do you get an exception?

Comment: The value of some_id is not empty. And I am not getting any error at all but the variables are not being imported because the code in views.py is not executing. If I add the connection variable manually in my views.py, the code will execute using the connection variable.

Comment: I think we need to see connection.py

Comment: connection.py is above. It's only 1 variable that holds a connection string to my local database. Views.py is also updated with how I use the conn_string variable.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35863/discussion-between-brandon-and-newtothis)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With constant values, I typically put those into a file called `constants.py` and specify those values in all caps, which is a Python convention. So, I would replace "connection.py" with "constants.py" as such:

```
# constants.py
CONN_STRING = "host='localhost' dbname='test' user='postgres' password='pwd'"


# views.py
from constants import CONN_STRING

def location_where_connection_variables_needed(request, some_id):
    conn = psycopg2.connect(CONN_STRING)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
```

Also, make sure to clear out any .pyc files that might not be getting cleared out by manage.py. That can sometimes cause things not to work as expected. You might also stay away from `import *` since it's not as implicit (you can't see what you're importing) and it's easy to run into naming collisions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a global variable instead of a local one. Use it as

```
global conn_string = "host='localhost' dbname='test' user='postgres' password='pwd'"
```